# [mongodb]about shard and many collections

Tags: mongodb

My situation is:

1. I have a mongodb cluster with sharding
2. I considered that sharing is effecting for one collection with specified shard key
3. I insert a new collection through mongos

My question is:

Where and why the new collection stored?  If one shared is full, should the new collection auto store in another?

Thank you!

Comment: You can read the docs section about shard balancing http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-balancing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this;if you insert a unsharded collection, it will store in the primary shard which by default first shard, and if the primary shard was full, the new collection will not store in another shard.